# Image does not display in uploaded app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, itunes

I have created an app and uploaded it on `itunes` connect. In my app I am displaying a 'register' page which use as login. If the user has not logged in, the register page is displayed. I am reusing this page to update the user's details, such as their name, number, and email address. I have added four images for register, skip, update and cancel. These images are displaying perfectly in the simulator and `IPA` which is given to the client. I have uploaded it to iTunes connect and then downloaded the app, but my images are not displaying.

**This is the code which i used to add images.**

```
 ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];



    appDelegate = (TaxiAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    userID = nil ;
    if (appDelegate.loginData)
    {
        LoginData *loginData = nil ;
        loginData = appDelegate.loginData ;
        userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[loginData userid]];
    } 
    theDataObject.userID = userID;

    NSLog(@"userID : %@",userID);

    if ([userID length] != 0) {
        [btnSubmit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Update.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [btnSubmit addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(updateUserData) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [skipButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [skipButton addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(cancelBtnClicked) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        txtUserName.text = [appDelegate.loginData name];
        txtEmail.text = [appDelegate.loginData email];
        txtPhone.text = [appDelegate.loginData phoneno];

    }else {
        [btnSubmit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_register.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnSubmit addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(btnSubmitClicked) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [skipButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_skip.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [skipButton addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(btnSkip) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    //

}
```

Buttons are responding for their action events but the images are not displaying.

**UPDATE**

And yes, my app is already in iTunes the update function is added as add version in my existing app.

I have not added @2x image for my button icons, is it necessary to do so?

Also, in my first version, I am displaying image using IB, but in the update I am setting the image on button programatically.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to include images with `@2x`, but it is recommended. If the user's device supports retina display, the app will look for the image with the `@2x` which should have a higher resolution. For example, a tab image may be 26x26 pixels. The same tab icon for retina may be 52x52px and have @2x in the name. You must include the original image.

Comment: In Xcode, find the images that are not appearing. Delete them. Then drag them back into the relevant folder (Supporting Files -> Images perhaps!?). Make sure `Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)` is checked. It could be that the path to your images are to your local machine.

Comment: @patrik thanx for reply, And yes i have checked "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)".

Answer (score 0):

On which device you are running the app ? If you are running the app on iPhone 4/4s or iPad 3 then , if you not add the @2x images  it doesn't display because it takes @2x images .

Comment: yes, i am running app on iphone 4s,but it was displaying image befor i have added version of my app.

Comment: and also in my first version i am displaying image using IB but in update i am setting image on button programetically.